# Want to play video from RTSP Server in my android device

Tags: android, rtsp

I have to create a demo on playing video from RTSP Server but I unable to get suitable code or method by which the video will played on my Android device from RTSP server. I have read the documentations on the same from the web but nothing going to help me for implementing the same for my android phone. Please suggest me for the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code taken from android documentation might help you (It is for audio media):

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

As you are trying to stream from RTSP server so your URL will be something like rtsp://...